# ¿Cómo mostrar el contenido de la página sin iniciar sesión en PHP?

Tags: php, bootstrap-3, sesiones

Código de la página principal:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'funcs/conection.php';
require 'funcs/funcs.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
    header("Location: index.php");
}
$idUsuario=$_SESSION['id_usuario'];
$sql="SELECT id, nombre FROM usuarios WHERE id='$idUsuario'";
$result=$mysqli->query($sql);
$row=$result->fetch_assoc();
?>
```

Código del cierre de sesión:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location: login.php");  
?>
```

Lo que quiero es que al cerrar sesión, pueda seguir viendo el contenido de la página. Algo así como YouTube...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano gracias por la ayuda que se brinde.

Comment: ¿? Por lo que expones solo se me ocurre que aquellos elementos y contenidos que desees sigan disponibles aún con sin iniciar sesión o posterior al cerrarla, quites la obligatoriedad que debe estar iniciada sesión para su acceso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo, en el código de cierre de sesión, además del

```
session_destroy();
```

también resetearia la variables importantes de la sesión, y luego redirigiria de nuevo a la página principal.

En la página principal, en lugar de:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"]){      
 header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Pintaría siempre la página completa, y solo en las zonas donde un inicio de sesión influya, pintar contenido de sesión si está iniciada o contenido estándar si no lo está.